# Creating Wordpress Category at the time of Theme Activation

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am going to create a function that will check whether if a Category named **Testimonials** is already available or not. If it is available do noting, whereas if it is not there, then create a new Category named **Testimonials**. I am using following code but nothing happened at the time of theme activation. What is missing?

```
function create_my_cat () {
    if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');    
        if (!get_cat_ID('testimonials')) {
            wp_create_category('testimonials');
        }
    }
}
add_action ('create_category', 'create_my_cat');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The action `create_category` runs when a new category is created.

You want your category creation function to run when the theme is activated. The relevant action is [`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme).

Drop this in your theme's *functions.php* and you should be good to go:

```
function create_my_cat () {
    if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
        if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Testimonials' ) ) {
            wp_create_category( 'Testimonials' );
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_my_cat' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have searched for automatic category creation and found that taxonomy.php will be needed to add in the code.

Also I have change code in functions.php:
`code`
 function create_my_cat () {
  if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
   require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');    
   if (!get_cat_ID('Testimonials')) {
    wp_create_category('Testimonials');
   }
  }
 }
`code`

and added <?php create_my_cat (); ?> in the header.php just before </head> and it worked.

Comment: Whether you capitalize the 'T' is your choice and not going to impact the functionality of the function. It might be that you found information that the including/requiring of _taxonomy.php_ is necessary, but it's not. You found misinformation. Whatever the case, the relevant bit is using the `after_setup_theme` hook.

Comment: @Johanned Pille Just tested your code, but got undefined function wp_create_category error. When I include taxpnomy.php code again it worked fine.

Comment: @Kash Fair enough. Must not be available outside admin area by default. Will update the answer accordingly for future reference. Anyhow, key is the different action hook.

Comment: @Johanned Pille You are right! I have also updated my functions.php file with your provided code and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks again for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you have already used a function my_theme_name_setup() {} you don't need another function. One more *note to mention; you can also use category_exists instead of get_cat_ID(), so the full code example is:

```
function my_theme_name_setup() {

    if( file_exists( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php' ) ) :
        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php' );

            if( ! category_exists( 'name' ) ) :

                wp_create_category( 'name' );

            endif;// Category exists

    endif;// File exists 

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_name_setup' );
```