# Create Taxonomy To Custom Post Type After Theme Activation

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I need help
How can I create taxonomy to custom post type after theme activation?
example case:
I have custom post type *'book'* and custom taxonomy *'genre'* for my custom post type. This is easy way when add code to *functions.php*, but i need to auto create *horor, comedy, fiction* to 'genre' when theme activation (after_theme_setup)

Very interest with this topic [Creating Wordpress Category at the time of Theme Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389387/creating-wordpress-category-at-the-time-of-theme-activation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to automatically add terms to existing custom taxonomy.

Assumption:: I've assumed that the post type 'book' is already registered and the custom taxonomy 'genre' is also already registered.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpso2523951_add_taxonomy_genre' );
    function wpso2523951_add_taxonomy_genre(){
        $custom_post_type = 'book';
        $custom_taxonomy = 'genre';
        $required_terms = [ 'horror'=>'Horror',
                            'comedy'=>'Comedy',
                            'fiction'=>'Fiction',
                        ];
        if( post_type_exists( $custom_post_type ) && taxonomy_exists( $custom_taxonomy ) ){
                register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $custom_taxonomy, $custom_post_type);
                foreach($required_terms as $slug=>$term_name){
                    wp_insert_term(
                              $term_name, 
                              $custom_taxonomy,
                              [
                                'description'=> $term_name.' genre.',
                                'slug' => $slug,
                              ]
                            );
                    }

            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try this code to theme this morning. Register post_type 'book', register_taxonomy 'genre'. Re-activate my theme but nothing happen, Horror, Comedy, and Fiction not added to the list

What wrong?